# springdoc-openapi: How to add example of POST request?

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

Have the following method of Controller:

```
    @ApiResponses(value = {@ApiResponse(responseCode = "200")})
    @GetMapping(value = API_URI_PREFIX + PRODUCTS_URI, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public Flux<Product> getProducts(@Valid @NotNull PagingAndSorting pagingAndSorting) {
   }
```

I need to find a way how to show in `Swagger` example of `PagingAndSorting` object.

I am using `springdoc-api` v1.4.3.

Answer (score 16):

You can use @ExampleObject annotation.

Note that you can also in the examples use the ref  @ExampleObject(ref="..."), if you want to reference an sample existing object. Or ideally, fetch the examples from external configuration file and add them using OpenApiCustomiser, like it's done in this test:

- https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/blob/master/springdoc-openapi-webmvc-core/src/test/java/test/org/springdoc/api/app90/SpringDocTestApp.java

Here is sample code using @ExampleObject:

```
@PostMapping("/test/{id}")
public void testme(
    @PathVariable("id") String id, 
    @RequestBody(
        content = @Content(
            examples = {
                @ExampleObject(
                    name = "Person sample",
                    summary = "person example",
                    value = "{\"email\": test@gmail.Com,"
                            + "\"firstName\": \"josh\","
                            + "\"lastName\": \"spring...\""
                            + "}"
                )
})) PersonDTO personDTO) { }
```

If you are using the `@RequestBody` Spring annotation in the controller you need to differentiate the two, for example by using `@io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody` for the Swagger annotation. This prevents the null param problem mentioned in the comments below.

Comment: What is "content" in @RequestBody(content = ....)? Doesn't compile.

Comment: OK. I tried to use import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody; Now it compiles, but RequestBody argument does not work. Value of param (variable) = null.

Comment: @brianbro - do you have example on how to fetch external configuration file as ExampleObject's value?. Tried this but not working:


test(@Valid @RequestBody(content = @Content(examples = {@ExampleObject(name = "Example Body", summary = "Example Body", ref = "exampleFile.json")

where exampleFile.json is on my src/main/resource folder

Comment: If I use this -
@io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody(content = @Content(examples = { @ExampleObject( name = "Person sample", summary = "person example", value = "{"email": test@gmail.Com," + ""firstName": "josh"," + ""lastName": "spring..."" + "}") }))

I get below exception -

no viable alternative at input ',@io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody(content=@Content(examples={@ExampleObject(name="Person sample",summary="person example",value="{\"email\": test@gmail.Com,"+"\"firstName\": \"josh\","+"\"lastName\": \"spring...\""+"}")})))': NoViableAltException

Comment: Is there any way to add the resources file content to the `@ExampleObject`? I am trying to add the `@ExampleObject` from the `resources file` using `ref` but its not working for some reason. I have posted my question:  stackoverflow.com/q/71616547/7584240

Comment: Don't forget to include the `name` attribute when using the `ref` in the `@ExampleObject`.  The examples are defined as a map in the swagger.json.

Comment: link expired

https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/blob/master/springdoc-openapi-webmvc-core/src/test/java/test/org/springdoc/api/app90/SpringDocTestApp.java

Answer (score 4):

@ExampleObject can be used for @RequestBody and @ApiResponse to add examples for springdoc openapi : https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/blob/master/springdoc-openapi-javadoc/src/test/java/test/org/springdoc/api/app90/HelloController.java

```
@RestController
public class HelloController {

    /**
     * Test 1.
     *
     * @param hello the hello
     */
    @GetMapping("/test")
    @ApiResponses(value = { @ApiResponse(description = "successful operation",content = { @Content(examples = @ExampleObject(name = "500", ref = "#/components/examples/http500Example"), mediaType = "application/json", schema = @Schema(implementation = User.class)), @Content(mediaType = "application/xml", schema = @Schema(implementation = User.class)) }) })
    public void test1(String hello) {
    }

    /**
     * Test 2.
     *
     * @param hello the hello
     */
    @PostMapping("/test2")
    @RequestBody(
            description = "Details of the Item to be created",
            required = true,
            content = @Content(
                    schema = @Schema(implementation = User.class),
                    mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
                    examples = {
                            @ExampleObject(
                                    name = "An example request with the minimum required fields to create.",
                                    value = "min",
                                    summary = "Minimal request"),
                            @ExampleObject(
                                    name = "An example request with all fields provided with example values.",
                                    value = "full",
                                    summary = "Full request") }))
    public void test2(String hello) {
    }

}
```

if you want to add OpenApiCustomiser in order to load your examples from resources you will need to start with something like this:
https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/blob/master/springdoc-openapi-javadoc/src/test/java/test/org/springdoc/api/app90/SpringDocTestApp.java

```
@Bean
    public OpenApiCustomiser openApiCustomiser(Collection<Entry<String, Example>> examples) {
        return openAPI -> {
            examples.forEach(example -> {
                openAPI.getComponents().addExamples(example.getKey(), example.getValue());
            });
        };
    }
```

For header, cookie, query or path params you can use @Parameter: https://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/v2.0.0-RC3/apidocs/io/swagger/v3/oas/annotations/Parameter.html

with ParameterIn enum: https://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/v2.0.0/apidocs/io/swagger/v3/oas/annotations/enums/ParameterIn.html

e.g.

```
@Parameter(in = ParameterIn.PATH, name = "id", description="Id of the entity to be update. Cannot be empty.",
        required=true, examples = {@ExampleObject(name = "id value example", value = "6317260b825729661f71eaec")})
```

Another way is to add @Schema(type = "string", example = "min") on your DTO. e.g. : https://www.dariawan.com/tutorials/spring/documenting-spring-boot-rest-api-springdoc-openapi-3/

Answer (score 0):

If someone is still interested, this is how examples can be added programmatically to a specific endpoint:

```
@Bean
 public OpenApiCustomiser mockExamples() {
    return openAPI ->
        getRequestBodyContent(openAPI, PXL_MOCK_PATH + "/transactions", "application/json").ifPresent(request ->
            Arrays.stream(PxlMockCase.values()).forEach(mockCase -> {
                request.addExamples(
                    mockCase.name(),
                    new Example()
                        .description(mockCase.getDescription())
                        .value(TransactionCodeRequest.builder().accountId(mockCase.getAccountId()).workflowId(15).build())
                );
            }));
}

private Optional<MediaType> getRequestBodyContent(OpenAPI api, String path, String bodyType) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(api.getPaths())
        .map(paths -> paths.get(path))
        .map(PathItem::getPost)
        .map(Operation::getRequestBody)
        .map(RequestBody::getContent)
        .map(content -> content.get(bodyType));
}
```

Answer (score -4):

If we are using spring boot, to add it to our Maven project, we need a dependency in the pom.xml file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SpringConfig {                                    
    @Bean
    public Docket api() { 
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)  
          .select()                                  
          .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())              
          .paths(PathSelectors.any())                          
          .build();                                           
    }
}
```

**Configuration Without Spring Boot**

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
      .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
 
    registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
      .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
}
```

**Verify:**
To verify that Springfox is working, you can visit the following URL in your browser:
http://localhost:8080/our-app-root/api/v2/api-docs

To use Swagger UI, one additional Maven dependency is required:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

You can test it in your browser by visiting http://localhost:8080/our-app-root/swagger-ui.html

Comment: @user471011 is looking for a solution with SpringDoc, and your example is with SpringFox.