# Springdoc Openapi - Add Response Example Value

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, openapi, springdoc-openapi-ui

I'm trying to add example response values to my springdoc-openapi swagger documentation.

Like replace the "string" with "Mark Twain" etc.

[image]

I tried using this solution - [springdoc-openapi: How to add example of POST request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63465763/springdoc-openapi-how-to-add-example-of-post-request)

I'm already using `org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody` in my class.

If I use this -

```java
@io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody(content = @Content(examples = {
                @ExampleObject(
                        name = "Person sample",
                        summary = "person example",
                        value =
                                "{\"email\": test@gmail.Com,"
                                        + "\"firstName\": \"josh\","
                                        + "\"lastName\": \"spring...\""
                                        + "}")
        }))
```

I get below exception -

```
no viable alternative at input ',@io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody(content=@Content(examples={@ExampleObject(name="Person sample",summary="person example",value="{\"email\": test@gmail.Com,"+"\"firstName\": \"josh\","+"\"lastName\": \"spring...\""+"}")})))': NoViableAltException
```

Can anyone give me a solution please?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This worked for me

```
@Schema( type = "string", example = "Clark Kent")
private String name;
```